# Response timeout xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin

Im trying to get JSON from server, using HttpWebRequest. But, trying different urls with different JSON Im always getting "Request time out". Here is my code:

```
//url = "http://46.105.85.199:3000/api/books
        // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Timeout = 300000;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string output = reader.ReadToEnd();

        response.Close();
        return output;`
```

and JSON:

```
[
 {
"metaData": {
  "title": "Гарри Поттер и Принц-полукровка (Росмэн) -0",
  "language": "ru",
  "date": "2005",
  "creator": "Джоан Кэтлин Роулинг",
  "creatorFileAs": "Джоан Кэтлин Роулинг",
  "publisher": "РОСМЭН",
  "description": "",
  "subject": "child_adv"
},
"chapters": [
  {
    "id": "cover",
    "href": "OEBPS/cover.xhtml",
    "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
  },
...
],
"name": "legion.epub",
"url": "/upload/common/legion.epub",
"lastMark": null,
"cover": "./client/upload/images/missing.jpg",
"id": 8,
"readerId": null,
"teamId": null
  }
]
```

And so on. I tried also get book by id and chapters, but with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to narrow down the problem start with a simple get request to a third-party server like google.com with neither `Accept` nor `ContentType` specified.

If the timeout does not reproduce than you are probably having a problem on the server hiding behind the `url`. If timeout persists than you might be having a problem on client (device/emulator) or something in between like a web proxy/wifi router/etc.

In order to check the latter, make the same request from your PC i.e. standard browser. Is it retrieving the response fast?

Comment: Yes it is. The problem appeared when 'chapters' JSON was added to the response.

Comment: @LukaBaryshych I do not quite get your comment, You say that when requested from a PC the response is retrieved fast, right? And then you say that the problem appeared when something is appended into the response i.e. server action, right? I don't get it. Either way, is the answer accepted?

Comment: When the client was written, it worked with a simple JSON. Then, the API was changed ("chapters" was added), and the client broke up. Looks like the problem is in the server, because I can retrieve response from the PC, but not from my smartphone.

Comment: @LukaBaryshych If you can retrieve the data from PC but cannot get it from the smartphone than the problem is on device i.e. NOT on the server. By the way, how much data do you see on the PC when you receive the data, how many `chapters`?